# OS selection menu at boot time flashes and loads windows

Tags: dual-boot

I set windows 7 to load by default by editing grub file. I set the time to display os selection menu at 0.5 seconds. Now the ubuntu's pink os selection screen flashes away too quickly. I tried pressing all the keys but none seen to freeze that menu.

How do I boot Ubuntu again?

Answer (score 0):

You could boot from a live CD, mount your disk partition and edit the `/etc/default/grub` file on the disk.
You would search for a line like this:
`GRUB_TIMEOUT=0.5`
and change the timeout to something else like 5 (5 sec).

That should give you more time.
If it does not solve your issue* or if you have problems* or need more detailed instructions, please leave me a comment.

<sub>(*) In this case it would be useful if you could post the contents of this file as an edit to your question.</sub>